# Convert .unity scene files to YAML without touching prefabs

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there any utility out there that will convert a .unity scene file to YAML without affecting the rest of the prefabs and assets? I've found instructions to change the Asset Serialization in the editor, but it affects all assets, where I would like to only do our scene files. (Our project has a large number of files and converting them all is too much risk at this point in the project.)

Answer (score 2):

For as far as I know, there is no selective serialization option. If you serialize to text (YAML in this case), that will happen for all of Unity's internal asset types (scenes, prefabs, scriptable objects, etc.). Of course this does not apply to any of the external assets.

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of your project, switch serialization to text. Copy the reserialized yaml scene file back into your main project, where you set the serialization to mixed.